# Little CSS animation on hover

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

Trying to create something like this. [image]

I can't use `letter-spacing.` I created this code, but it doesn't work well.

http://jsfiddle.net/pyqq8wfe/

```css
.refreshed_logo {
  font-family: ProximaNovaBold;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
}
.logo_wrapper {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 250px;
  position: absolute;
}
.refreshed_logo:after {
  content: 'digital';
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 18px;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 4px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  text-indent: 8px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  transition-property: width, height;
  transition-duration: 0.2s, 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 0s, 0.2s;
  -o-transition-property: width, height;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.2s, 0.2s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0s, 0.2s;
  -moz-transition-property: width, height;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s, 0.2s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0s, 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition-property: width, height;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s, 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s, 0.2s;
}
.refreshed_logo:hover:after {
  width: 71px;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.5s;
  transition: width 0.5s;
  text-indent: 2px;
}
.logo_wrapper:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="/" class="logo_wrapper">
  <span class="refreshed_logo">
               Granat
            </span>
</a>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/pyqq8wfe/4/) is the best that I could come up with. It manually introduces a space between 'd' and 'i' in the unhovered state which is removed on hover.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you cannot use `letter-spacing` or split the words, below is an approach using `border-right` which along with `overflow: hidden` setting hides all characters after 'd'. On hover they are revealed and thus produce the effect.

```css
.refreshed_logo {
  font-family: ProximaNovaBold;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
}
.logo_wrapper {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 250px;
  position: absolute;
}
.refreshed_logo:after {
  content: 'digital';
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  /*text-align: center; not required */
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 18px;
  color: white;
  /* following properties were added */
  padding-left: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-right: 5px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* end of addition */
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  transition-property: width, height;
  transition-duration: 0.2s, 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 0s, 0.2s;
}
.refreshed_logo:hover:after {
  width: 65px;
  transition: width 0.5s;
}
.logo_wrapper:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="/" class="logo_wrapper">
  <span class="refreshed_logo">
               Granat
            </span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've try to have the same result there's maybe better :

Last edit : for hide the others letter i've use the same color of the background, and only change the first letter color.

**CSS :**

```
.titre{
    font-size:20pt;
}

.sstitre{
    font-size:10pt;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:red;
    background-color:red;
    border-radius:10px;
    padding-left:4px;
    padding-right:2px;
    width:10px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow:hidden;
    transition:width 0.5s;
}

.sstitre::first-letter{
    color:white;
}

.titre:hover .sstitre{
 width:40px;   
color:white;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<span class="titre">Granat<span class="sstitre">digital</span></span>
```

[JSFidle](http://jsfiddle.net/he12nh97/3/)

Comment: While that's definitely better, he did say he cannot use `letter-spacing`.

Comment: I've mentioned that I can't use letter spacing.

Comment: Edited !! Without letter spacing and entire word.